# message-driven-channel-adapter consuming slowly

Tags: spring-integration

I have below configuration to consume messages from a queue.

`<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter                                   destination="ResponseQueue" 
        channel="responseChannel" 
        auto-startup="false" 
        max-messages-per-task="50"
        receive-timeout="10000"
        concurrent-consumers="5"
        task-executor="receivingTaskExecutor"
        max-concurrent-consumers="50" 
        idle-consumer-limit="1"
        idle-task-execution-limit="1"
        recovery-interval="60000"/>`

The receivingTaskExecutor is configured as org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, with core pool size 5, max 50, and queue capacity as 100.

I notice that it is consuming messages very slowly. On java visual VM, i only see 5 receivingTaskExecutor threads active. What is wrong in my configuration that is preventing it from dynamically scaling to full strength? There are thousands of messages on queue to be processed.

Thank you

Comment: What is downstream? If the ResponseChannel is being blocked by something else it will not be able to add more messages.

Comment: ResponseChannel is a direct channel and i have a transformer and stored-proc-outbound-gateway that is savings part of each message to database in same thread.

Comment: Haven't you played with those `idle-consumer-limit` and `idle-task-execution-limit` ? And why pool queue is so small? How much the JDBC connection pool is ?

Comment: I have not played with those, what can i do with these in this case.  Pool queue is small as i expect the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to create new threads to keep pool small, correct? JDBC connection pool size is 20, i know these is slowness at jdbc level but i was thinking why its not using all threads to consume queue and may be bottleneck at jdbc level. Thanks

Comment: A new thread is only started if, when a message is received, all workers are  busy. If all 5 threads are stuck for a long time, a 6th thread won't start until one of them returns to the container and sees that the others are all busy. See `scheduleNewInvokerIfAppropriate()`. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and look for these log entries: `logger.debug("Raised scheduled invoker count: " + this.scheduledInvokers.size());`.

Comment: Thanks gary, i see this printed but not more than 5 active threads -
[receivingTaskExecutor-4] DEBUG o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Raised scheduled invoker count: 11
[receivingTaskExecutor-5] DEBUG o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Raised scheduled invoker count: 12
[receivingTaskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Raised scheduled invoker count: 13